# What kinds of mythological questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Understanding the context and influences of certain pieces of literature requires understanding the mythology of the culture it came out of.  So I would think some questions about mythology should be relevant.  On the other hand, this is not mythology.SE, so other questions (e.g., "What's the difference between Odin and Zeus?") should probably not.

Here are some ill-thought-out examples to start the discussion.  Feel free to edit better examples into this question:

1. Where do the Sirens in the Odyssey come from?
2. How did the idea for the Sirens arise or evolve in Greek mythology?
3. In Greek mythology, do Sirens want to lure men to their deaths?

Answer (score 14):

I vote to welcome any mythology questions that are **connected to a written source**. (But see also [Does Oral-Literature count as literature here?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/636/481))

Using this as a distinction, only the first of your example questions remains on-topic. If it is not directly answerable from relevant work, we should be allowed to draw from other mythos as well.

However, general questions about mythology, if they aren't asking about a particular written work, aren't really our area.

<sub>Note that this doesn't contradict with previous consensus about overlaps with Mythology SE</sub>

Comment: -1 for "*asking a mythology question on Mythology SE probably makes more sense*". Before we try to ship out content to other sites, let's decide on **what kinds of question about mythology are on-topic here** (which is what this question is actually asking). Then only those which *aren't* can be taken to Mythology SE instead.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  I still think it makes more sense, but I'll remove that bit for the sake of the argument

Comment: Downvote changed to an upvote.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  I live to serve

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the other question.  So are you saying the oral tradition (distinct from written works) should not be on topic.  I mostly agree with [this answer](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/a/162/68) which says storytelling is literature, and I wouldn't mind questions about oral storytelling here.